# What's the meaning of 'blacklisted' on GStreamer?

Tags: linux, plugins, mips, cross-compiling, gstreamer

I'm trying to cross-compile GStreamer. Version is 1.2.3. Host PC's OS is x86 linux and Target system's OS is MIPSEL linux OS.

I succeeded to compile gstreamer and plugins for target device. And `gst-launch-1.0` could be executed. So I tried to use basic plugin, libgstvideotestsrc. But it didn't work. So I ran ```gst-inspect-1.0' to inspect plugins then I found the result like below.

```
# gst-inspect-1.0 -b
Blacklisted files:
  libgstinterlace.so
  libgstfbdevsink.so
  libgstgeometrictransform.so
  libgstmultifile.so
  libgstencodebin.so
  libgstfestival.so
  libgstlevel.so
  libgstdvdspu.so
  libgstauparse.so
  libgsty4menc.so
  libgstvideofilter.so
  libgstvideoscale.so
  libgstaccurip.so
  libgstvideoconvert.so
  libgstaudioparsers.so
  libgsttcp.so
  libgstvolume.so
  libgstcoreelements.so
  libgstmpegtsdemux.so
  libgstid3tag.so
  libgstadpcmdec.so
  libgstmfc.so
  libgstrtpmanager.so
  libgstaudiotestsrc.so
  libgstdeinterlace.so
  libgstdebug.so
  libgstplayback.so
  libgstspeed.so
  libgstasfmux.so
  libgsticydemux.so
  libgstmpegpsdemux.so
  libgstalaw.so
  libgstwavparse.so
  libgstpnm.so
  libgstnavigationtest.so
  libgstcamerabin2.so
  libgstsdpelem.so
  libgstisomp4.so
  libgstliveadder.so
  libgstmpegtsmux.so
  libgstautodetect.so
  libgstmultipart.so
  libgstvideofiltersbad.so
  libgstaudioresample.so
  libgstautoconvert.so
  libgstdvbsuboverlay.so
  libgstid3demux.so
  libgstvideobox.so
  libgstgio.so
  libgstdtmf.so
  libgstremovesilence.so
  libgstreplaygain.so
  libgstaudioconvert.so
  libgstcutter.so
  libgstgaudieffects.so
  libgstdvb.so
  libgstaudiovisualizers.so
  libgstudp.so
  libgstimagefreeze.so
  libgstadder.so
  libgstpcapparse.so
  libgstmxf.so
  libgstshapewipe.so
  libgstgdp.so
  libgstwavenc.so
  libgstshm.so
  libgstflv.so
  libgstfreeverb.so
  libgstoss4audio.so
  libgstsubenc.so
  libgstaudiorate.so
  libgstinter.so
  libgsttypefindfunctions.so
  libgstvideorate.so
  libgstrtp.so
  libgstcoloreffects.so
  libgstmpegpsmux.so
  libgstivtc.so
  libgstjpegformat.so
  libgstsmpte.so
  libgstalphacolor.so
  libgstsubparse.so
  libgstaudiofxbad.so
  libgstvideomixer.so
  libgstmulaw.so
  libgstdebugutilsbad.so
  libgsteffectv.so
  libgstfieldanalysis.so
  libgstadpcmenc.so
  libgstrawparse.so
  libgstavi.so
  libgstdataurisrc.so
  libgstapetag.so
  libgstinterleave.so
  libgstmidi.so
  libgstrtsp.so
  libgstapp.so
  libgstalpha.so
  libgstaudiofx.so
  libgstvideocrop.so
  libgstvideotestsrc.so
  libgstspectrum.so
  libgstbayer.so
  libgstaiff.so
  libgstsegmentclip.so
  libgstfrei0r.so

Total count: 106 blacklisted files
```

I wonder the meaning of 'blacklisted' and how I should approach this problem. Please let me know if you need several information to resolve this issue.

Here is my build configuration for GStreamer.

```
#PACKAGES: Name + version
export GST_PLUGIN_BASE="gst-plugins-base-1.2.3"
export GST_PLUGIN_GOOD="gst-plugins-good-1.2.3"
export GST_PLUGIN_BAD="gst-plugins-bad-1.2.3"


#HOST & Build configuration.
export HOST="mips-linux-gnu"
export BUILD="i686-pc-linux-gnu"


#Set path for file system.
export BUILD_PATH="~~~~~"
export ROOTFS_PATH="${BUILD_PATH}/rootfs"
export MIPS_LIB="~~~"
export INSTALL_PATH="${ROOTFS_PATH}/usr"
export INSTALL_PATH_LIB="${ROOTFS_PATH}/usr/lib"

#Compiler options
export PATH="${PATH}:${INSTALL_PATH}/bin"
export CFLAGS="-I${ROOTFS_PATH}/usr/include  -I${ROOTFS_PATH}/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I${ROOTFS_PATH}/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I${ROOTFS_PATH}/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I${ROOTFS_PATH}/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -mno-compact-eh -EL"   
export CPPFLAGS="-I${ROOTFS_PATH}/usr/include  -I${ROOTFS_PATH}/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I${ROOTFS_PATH}/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I${ROOTFS_PATH}/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I${ROOTFS_PATH}/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -mno-compact-eh -EL"
export CXXFLAGS=$CPPFLAGS
export GST_CHECK_CFLAGS="-I${ROOTFS_PATH}/usr/include -I${ROOTFS_PATH}/usr/include/glib-2.0/include" 
export PKG_CONFIG="/usr/bin/pkg-config" 
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PATH}:${ROOTFS_PATH}/lib/pkgconfig/:${ROOTFS_PATH}/usr/lib/pkgconfig/:${ROOTFS_PATH}/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/lib/pkgconfig"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib:/usr/local/lib"
export CC="~~~mips-linux-gnu-gcc -EL"
export CXX="~~~mips-linux-gnu-g++ -EL"



cd ${BUILD_PATH}


#GStreamer 1.2.3
#http://greenday96.egloos.com/viewer/4627046
wget http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gstreamer/$GSTREAMER.tar.xz
tar xf $GSTREAMER.tar.xz
cd $GSTREAMER
./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PATH --build=$BUILD  --host=$HOST  --disable-nls --disable-static 
sudo make 
sudo make install 
cd ..

#gst-plugin-base 1.2.3 
wget http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-base/$GST_PLUGIN_BASE.tar.xz
tar xf $GST_PLUGIN_BASE.tar.xz
cd $GST_PLUGIN_BASE
./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PATH --build=$BUILD  --host=$HOST  --disable-nls --disable-static --disable-examples --disable-pango
sudo make 
sudo make install 
cd ..


# gst-plugin-good-1.2.3 
# http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-good/gst-plugins-good-1.2.3.tar.xz
wget http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-good/$GST_PLUGIN_GOOD.tar.xz
tar xf $GST_PLUGIN_GOOD.tar.xz
cd $GST_PLUGIN_GOOD
./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PATH --build=$BUILD  --host=$HOST  --disable-nls --disable-static --disable-valgrind --disable-equalizer --disable-flx --disable-goom --disable-goom2k1 --disable-matroska --disable-monoscope  --disable-oss  --disable-cairo  --disable-gdk_pixbuf   --disable-soup  --disable-libpng --disable-gst_v4l2
sudo make 
sudo make install 
cd ..


# gst-plugin-bad-1.2.3 
# http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-bad/gst-plugins-bad-1.2.3.tar.xz
wget http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-bad/$GST_PLUGIN_BAD.tar.xz
tar xf $GST_PLUGIN_BAD.tar.xz
cd $GST_PLUGIN_BAD
./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PATH --build=$BUILD  --host=$HOST  --disable-nls --disable-static   --disable-y4m --disable-siren --disable-librfb  --disable-yadif --disable-smooth --disable-videoparsers --disable-decklink --disable-valgrind --disable-directfb --disable-examples 
sudo make 
sudo make install 
cd ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it was blacklisted as I have built kvssink which have dependencies on other libraries. And GStreamer doesn't found them.

It was like that:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 kvssink

(gst-plugin-scanner:22): GStreamer-WARNING **: 13:07:28.097: Failed to load plugin '/root/bin/producer/libgstkvssink.so': libproducer.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
(gst-plugin-scanner:22): GStreamer-WARNING **: 13:07:28.204: Failed to load plugin '/root/bin/producer/libproducer.so': libcproducer.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

To confirm libraries issue I've used ldd

```
ldd libgstkvssink.so
```

Which will list all dependencies with paths were they may be found in system.
my libraries libcproducer.so and libcproducer.so were not found.

Based on path pritned for other visible libraries

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc3c1a6000)
libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f064d24d000)
```

I just copied missing libraries to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
In my case it was:

```
cp libcproducer.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
cp libproducer.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

And than:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 kvssink
```

prints plugin details.

I've resolved that thanks to information in this thread:
[Linking against external libraries in gstreamer plugin using autotools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825881/linking-against-external-libraries-in-gstreamer-plugin-using-autotools)

Answer (score 7):

if you want to know for sure why these plugins are blacklisted, you can remove "registry.dat" (run locate to find out its location), then rerun gst-inspect , the plugins will be examined once again and the reason for blacklisting them should be printed.

There can be several reasons why they are blacklisted, if you do this you should find them out.

Alternatively, you can also run gst-inspect location_of_the_dynamic_library.so

Comment: It's ```/root/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/registry.mips.bin```. I'm checking this file. Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: In registry.mips.bin, I cannot find any meaningful information. It just shows that a plug-in is black-listed. I cannot catch the reason why it's black-listed.

Answer (score 6):

For gstreamer 1.8 gst-inspect-1.0 need to be launcged with additional GST_DEBUG=4 env var to view detailed reason (incompatible version in my case):

```sh
GST_DEBUG=4 gst-inspect-1.0  /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgst_some_plugin.so
```

```
...15-20 lines with non-interesting details...

0:00:00.035553207  4287     0x29f93c00 WARN      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:485:gst_plugin_register_func: plugin "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgst_some_plugin.so" has incompatible version (plugin: 1.10, gst: 1,8), not loading
Could not load plugin file: File "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgst_some_plugin.so" appears to be a GStreamer plugin, but it failed to initialize
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason. It's GLIB, not GStreamer.

To build GLIB for mipsel, I should set `glib_cv_uscore=no`. It's up to your embedded device. So please check your target hardware's CPU specification. So I made the build script for GLIB like below.

```
#Glib 2.42.1
wget ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.42/$GLIB.tar.xz
tar xf $GLIB.tar.xz 
cd $GLIB

#Build for MIPS
echo "ac_cv_func_posix_getgrgid_r=yes" >  mips.cache
echo "ac_cv_func_posix_getpwuid_r=yes" >>  mips.cache
echo "glib_cv_stack_grows=no" >> mips.cache
echo "glib_cv_uscore=no" >>mips.cache
./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PATH --host=$HOST  --cache-file=mips.cache --build=$BUILD 
make
make install 
cd ..
```

I got the clue from [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/gstreamer-embedded@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00644.html).